# How can I update constraints of the content of StackView? Will I have to Unembed first?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, ios9, uistackview

I have added four labels in an StackView. And now I want to provide them specific constraints via Storyboards. I tried but I was not able to make any change but when I first Unembed the Stackview, and set the constraints like Height and Width and then Added them in Stackview, their constraints preserved. So my question is can we update the constraints of the content of StackView without unembeding?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution but I am not deleting this question as StackView is new concept and many more developers can get this confusion so I think this answer will help them.

Just open the window where we set the constraints and update the constraint value which you want to update as you will not be able to change the height and width of the content after adding it into the Stack View. The only way I found "so far" is to update the value of constraints as I have shown in the following image.

[image]

The default width was 42 according to the text of UILabel but when I updated the value of width constraint, it worked for me!